# ActionController throws UnknownFormat while uploading a picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to upload a photo through my Rails app and everything is fine until I click on "update...". Then it throws me an `"ActionController::UnknownFormat"` error and fails. Here you can find the form I'm using, the update controller and the model I'm referring to.

Form:

```
<%= form_with(model: current_user, local: true, html: {multipart: true}) do |form| %>
                          <div class="field">
                            <%= form.label :profile_pic %>
                            <%= form.file_field :profile_pic, id: :profile_pic %>
                          </div>
                          <div class="actions">
                            <%= form.submit %>
                          </div>
                       <% end %>
```

Update method:

```
  def update
    @user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        render action: :edit
      end
    end
  end
```

Error seems to be here:

```
respond_to do |format|
```

model:

```
require 'digest'
class User < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :profile_pic, ProfilePicUploader
    attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_new_password
    after_create :build_profile 
    has_one :profile
    has_many :trips
    has_many :comments, through: :trips, source: :comments
    has_many :posts, through: :trips, source: :posts

    scope :recent_comments, ->{where("comments.created_at > ? AND user_id = ?", [6.months.ago, self.id]).limit(3)}
    #friends
    has_many :users

    validates :email, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false, message: 'El correo debe ser único'}, length: {in: 6..50, too_short: "debe tener al menos %{count} caracteres"}, format: {multiline: true,with: /^.+@.+$/, message: "formato de correo no valido"}

    validates :password, confirmation: true, length: {within: 4..20}, presence: {if: :password_required?}
    validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  def self.authenticate(email,password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    return user if user && user.authenticated?(password)
  end

  def authenticated?(password)
    self.hashed_password == encrypt(password)
  end

  protected
  def encrypt_new_password
    return if password.blank?
    self.hashed_password = encrypt(password)
  end
  def password_required?
    hashed_password.blank? || password.present?
  end
  def encrypt(string)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(string) 
  end
  def build_profile
    Profile.create(user: self, name: self.name, bio:"Im using Tripper!")  
  end
end
```

If anyone could tell me please what did I do wrong...

Comment: There's a lot of extraneous code in that model, for purposes of asking the question here.  You should isolate the problematic code and just post it.  The process of narrowing down to the problem is part of the due diligence to earn answers here--and you will often find your own answer in the process.  Also, you should post the trace of the error message in case (as seems quite possible) you are misinterpreting what it is telling you about error location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the `respond_to` block, but you didn't specify the format in which `edit` action should be rendered.

Try updating the `update` action as below:

```
def update
  @user = current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update(user_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render 'edit'} # Specify the format in which you are rendering the 'edit' page
      format.json { render json: @user.errors } # If required, specify a json format as well
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following by updating the `update` action

```
def update
    @user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully updated.'
        format.html {redirect_to user_path(@user) }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        render action: :edit
      end
    end
end
```

Hope to help